# Highlighter isn't highlighting what is matched in query analyzer

Tags: solr, highlighting

The content I'm trying to index contains dollar signs that should be indexed and matched, e.g., `$1`.

I've set up my schema to index the dollar sign, and am able to successfully match it with the query analyzer; searching for `$1` matches `$1`.

However, the highlighter doesn't seem to recognize the dollar sign.  When I submit a query for `$1`, the results do contain highlighted results, but the highlights appear like `$<em>1</em>`; the dollar sign is not highlighted.

How can I ensure that the highlighter will highlight the entirety of what is matched in the query analyzer tool?

Comment: Can you post the schema.xml definitions for the highlighting field and the solrconfig.xml stanza for the highlighting handler? At first glance, this sounds like it's still being run through a tokenizer which is chomping punctuation

Comment: Yep.  You're absolutely right, Chris.  I was distracting myself from the fact that I was indexing and querying one field (the new one), and highlighting another (the old one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACK!  The problem was that after tuning one of my fields just right, I was still highlighting the old, un-tuned field.  It appears that Solr is doing what I expect it to do now.